# for-comprehension, guard and RandomAccessFile.readLine

Tags: scala, for-loop, randomaccessfile, for-comprehension

Consider the following:

There is a textfile with a certain amount of lines, like:

> test.txt:
>       a
>       b
>       c
>       d
>       e
>       f
>       g
>       h

(each in there own line)

Then there is the following class used for parsing:

```
class MyAwesomeParser
{
    def parse(fileName: String, readLines: Int): IndexedSeq[String] =
    {
        val randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r")

        val x: IndexedSeq[String] = for
        {
            x <- 0 until readLines
            r = randomAccessFile.readLine()
        } yield r

        x
    }
}
```

Here come the tests:

```
class MyAwesomeParserTest extends WordSpec
{
    "MyAwesomeParser" when {
    "read" should {
      "parse only specified number of lines" in {
        val parser = new EdgeParser("")
        val x = parser.parse("test.txt", 5)

        assert(x.size == 5)
      }
    }

    "MyAwesomeParser" when {
    "read" should {
      "parse only until end of file" in {
        val parser = new EdgeParser("")
        val x = parser.parse("test.txt", 10)

        assert(x.size == 8)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second test is the problematic one. Now of course you say, you're missing a guard here... well, well, if I add

```
x <- 0 until readLines if randomAccessFile.readLine != null
```

to the implementation then it skips a few lines, because readLine already consumes the line.

```
  r = randomAccessFile.readLine
  x <- 0 until readLines if r != null
```

will not work sadly, as first one line has to be assignment for comprehension.

Now I wonder, is it even possible with a for comprehension to loop until a given amount of times OR stop before based on that `readLine != null` condition?

Is my syntax just broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may encapsulate `randomAccessFile.readLine` in an `Option`, so that `null` will be changed to `None` and `value` to `Some(value)`.

Moreover, `Option` can be considered as a collection, so you may put it in the same for comprehension as the `IndexedSeq`:

```
for {
  x <- 0 until readLines
  r <- Option(randomAccessFile.readLine())
} yield r
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to your `parse` method, you could just use `getFilePointer` and `length`

```
def parse(fileName: String, readLines: Int): IndexedSeq[String] =
{
    val randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r")

    val x: IndexedSeq[String] = for
    {
        x <- 0 until readLines if randomAccessFile.getFilePointer < randomAccessFile.length
        r = randomAccessFile.readLine()
    } yield r

    x
}
```

However, instead of reinventing the wheel, I suggest you just use `scala.io.Source`:

```
def parse(fileName: String, readLines: Int): Iterator[String] =
  Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.take(readLines)
```

Comment: Ah, crap.. I tried to provide a small example, but I don't want a work around for my specific problem, but rather a generic solution